# Passing Array to Class Method for Selection Sort

Tags: c++, arrays, class, sorting

I'm supposed to use this to sort an array.

```
template <class T>
class Selection
{

private:
    T* ptr;

public:
    Selection(T len)
    {
        cout << "Allocating Selection ptr\n";

        //allocate memory for the pointer
        ptr = new T;
        *ptr = len;
    };

    T getobj(void)
    {
        return *ptr;
    };

    static SelectionSort(T arr[], int n)
    {
    //pos_min is short for position of min
        T pos_min, temp;

        for (int i = 0, j; i < n - 1; i++)
        {
            pos_min = i;//set pos_min to the current index of array

            for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
            {
                if (arr[j] < arr[pos_min])
                    pos_min = j;
            }
            //pos_min keeps track of the index that min is in

            //if pos_min no longer equals i than a smaller value must have been found
            if (pos_min != i)
            {
                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[pos_min];
                arr[pos_min] = temp;
            }
        }
    };
};
```

Created the array in main:

```
int arr1[10] = { 1, 2, 7, 4, 5 };
int m = sizeof(arr1) / sizeof(arr1[0])
```

Have no idea how to pass the array to the SelectionSort function in class Selection (it was void but I was trying stuff out with static because internet. So far everything I've tried leaves me with about 10-13 fatal errors)
None of which I understand.

What is the syntax to pass arr1 to the SelectionSort within Class Selection?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, try to change type of pos_min in SelectionSort function from T to int and add a void as a return value of this function.

Then, try to create an object of class Selection with type name in angle brackets, initialise an array and put it in class method. I mean try to do like this:

```
Selection<double> sel(5);
double ar[] = {5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
sel.SelectionSort(ar, 5);
```

Comment: That did it. Now after seeing this I understand what my friend was saying about using the object to call the function. I don't really get why but at least it works (I made a simple read for loop to cout the array and it is infact sorted) Thank you very much @deepv2 I just need to repeat this process for the other sort functions now.

Comment: Nevermind my dyslexia made me think it was sorted. But I'll figure it out, at least now I know the syntax to call a method func I think I just need to mess with some pointer stuff related to the actual sorting function